# Printing the sum of animals that are below a threshold

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-stream, bluej

I'm trying to solve an exercise from the book: Objects first with Java: A practical introduction using BlueJ.

The exercise goes as following:

> **Exercise 5.17** Rewrite the *printEndangered* method in your project to use Streams.

The original code is:

```
public void printEndangered(ArrayList<String> animalNames, int dangerThreshold)
{
    for(String animal : animalNames) {
        if(getCount(animal) <= dangerThreshold) {
            System.out.println(animal + " is endangered.");
        }
    }
}
```

My attempt looks like this:

```
sightings.stream()
    .filter(s -> animalNames.equals(s.getAnimal()))
    .filter(s -> s.getCount() <= dangerThreshold)
    .mapToInt(s -> s.getCount())
    .forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
```

Comment: What is `sightings` and how is it related to the original code?

Comment: Sightings is an ArrayList containing the sightings as objects of the class Sighting. Which holds info of the different sightings that have been made.

You can download the project files here: https://www.bluej.org/objects-first/resources/projects.zip Its from chapter 5: Animal-monitoring-v1

Comment: what does getCount do? and this line is weird: `.filter(s -> animalNames.equals(s.getAnimal()))`. you are comparing an arraylist with and animal object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `getCount()` method belongs to the class that contains `printEndangered`, not to `s`:

```
public void printEndangered(ArrayList<String> animalNames, int dangerThreshold) {
    animalNames.stream()
               .filter(animal -> getCount(animal) <= dangerThreshold)
               .map(animal -> animal + " is endangered.")
               .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sightings.stream()
//.filter(s -> animalNames.equals(s.getAnimal())) -- not required
.filter(s -> getCount(s) <= dangerThreshold)
//.mapToInt(s -> s.getCount()) -- not required
.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s + " is Endangered"));
```

Comment: `getCount()` different signature altogether?